# How to endlessly spawn an object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity. I like to know resources to the following problem: in every (say 3 second) a cube will spawn in the sky, and will drop in the ground, the process will continue with no ending.

I have to use some loop, but problem is that how to spawn repeatedly. I think for a game developer, it is very easy, so thanks for any help.

Comment: You would use a "true loop" that is, a loop that runs while true, so something like `while(true){ ... }` .... which will always run, forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to make the object appear every few seconds.You can use an `Coroutine` for this. You can do it like this:

```
private bool _spawning = true;
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
}

IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
{
    while (_spawning == true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); // wait 3 sec
         GameObject new_obstacle = Instantiate(obstacle, transform.position = new Vector3(2 /* x postion*/, 2/* y position*/ , 2/* z position*/), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

There is no end to this loop if `_spawning` is set to `true`

Answer (score 3):

Using a coroutine like @Tygo described is a great solution.

Another option would be to simply use the Update function

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public float seconds;

    private float elapsedSeconds;
    
    
    protected void Update()
    {
        elapsedSeconds += Time.deltaTime;
        if (elapsedSeconds >= seconds)
        {
            Instantiate(cubePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            elapsedSeconds = 0;
        }
    }
}
```